# Dplyr filter using dynamic column name and dynamic value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563885/dplyr-filter-using-dynamic-column-name-and-value) and marked as a duplicate. However, it is not a duplicate and received no answers. I'm asking again.

I have

```
df = data.frame(A=1:10, B=sample(c('TT', 'TG', 'GG'), 10, replace=T))
# df
#    A  B
#1   1 TG
#2   2 TG
#3   3 GG
#4   4 TT
#5   5 TT
#6   6 TT
#7   7 GG
#8   8 TT
#9   9 TG
#10 10 TT
```

If I specify the column I can use a dynamic list of values like:

```
> vals=c('TT', 'GG')
> df%>% filter(B %in% !!vals)
   A  B
1  3 GG
2  4 TT
3  5 TT
4  6 TT
5  7 GG
6  8 TT
7 10 TT
```

Now I want to add in `col='B'` to do something like:

```
df%>% filter(!!col %in% !!vals)
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Using

```
> paste(col, "==", sapply(vals, function(x){paste0("'", x, "'")}), collapse=" | ")
[1] "B == 'TT' | B == 'GG'"
```

The following monstrosity does work:

```
> df %>% filter_(paste(col, "==", sapply(vals, function(x){paste0("'", x, "'")}), collapse=" | "))
   A  B
1  3 GG
2  4 TT
3  5 TT
4  6 TT
5  7 GG
6  8 TT
7 10 TT
```

I'm really hoping there is a simple, dplyr-eseq syntax for this.

Comment: `df %>% filter(!!as.name(col) %in% !!vals)` from the accepted answer's comment works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the [tidy evaluation syntax](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), use:

```
df %>% filter(!!sym(col) %in% !!vals)
```

[`sym()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/sym) converts your string to a symbol, which dplyr knows to evaluate.

Also `df %>% filter(!!as.name(col) %in% !!vals)` works as @A.Suliman points out.